# Simple Form - Posting to a path

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to do something as follows:

```
<form action="/search" method="post">
<input type="text" name="searchterm">
</form>
```

And then using PHP - `$_POST['searchterm']` to get the value inside the `/search/index.php` file. - Is there a way to do this? or am I trying to do it the wrong way?

Comment: use session. store the values there Thats it, and input type submit as well

Comment: and how do you do that, where should I set the $_SESSION['searchtext'] ?

Comment: where is form is on same location?

Comment: The search form is on the homepage i.e index, then theres another file in /search, which is the search page index.

Comment: if this form and that address are the same, you can just omit whats inside the `action=""`, it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="Yourfilename.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm">
    <input type="text" name="age"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['age']?>">
       <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

in that file

```
<?php


session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $_SESSION['searchterm']=$_POST['searchterm'];


}
```

now in any file where you want to access the data

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['searchterm'];
```

Answer (score 1):

is your form on same directory try

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="searchterm">
</form>
```

if on other location:- give full url of index.php like http://example.com/search/index.php
or use absolute path of index.php in **action**

```
<form action="/search/index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="searchterm">
</form>
```

Comment: you have a typo `index,php`, and also a small detail, it will also work with this `/search/` <-- must have leading slash (it will also point to `/search/index.php`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add full path in form `action`. If the search folder is in same root directory then use

```
<form action="search/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

If `search` is a folder from server (ie, `localhost/search`) then use

```
<form action="/search/index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchterm">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And in `index.php`

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['searchterm'])){
    $value = $_POST['searchterm'];      
    $_SESSION['searchterm'] = $value;
    echo $value;
}
```